# Document Sets Vs Folders, managed metadata and automation using power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, document-set

We are trying to benefit from using folder structures and managed metadata to store and filter/search our SharePoint documents. so i created a term group >> with 2 term sets >> named "client" and "Doc Type", as follow:-

[image]

and at the same time we are storing the files into this folder structure as follow:-

-ClientName

```
-DocType

    -the documents
```

as follow:-

[image]

now there are 2 ways to implement the above:-

1. using SharePoint document sets
2. using regular folders, custom content type & Power Automate

using document sets we can set that when we create a new document set to have the related "client" and "Doc Type" fields and the related sub-folders auto created. while using regular folders, custom content type & Power Automate, i can do everything in power automate to create sub-folders and assign metadata to the document when they get created..

I always try to avoid using document sets because they are still on classic UI + they overcomplicate document management +  when i define document set it looks unaligned with what the user already do on their own sites, where they simply create folders and upload documents.. so is it wrong if i do not use document sets for my above scenario and rely on power automate to do the automation the way i want?

any ideas and thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Document sets would be better in my view, since it is out-of-the-box and more resilient than a custom solution. Additionally, modern SharePoint does support document sets.

Comment: but using document sets will not be aligned with what the users do on daily bases where they use their own team site to share and collaborate on documents inside regular folders.. what do you think?

Comment: The document set content type inherits from the folder content type, there isn't really much difference for users, except for more powerful functionality.